# The proxy url is not a well formed absolute uri string Error from Azure agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I self-host an agent on a stock Ubuntu 22.04. It runs behind a proxy and was running fine.
Today the agent went offline in the web interface. The agent's version is 3.220.0.

Upon manually starting `./runsvc.sh` on the agent (via systemd in my case), it shows an error. The log in `_diag` says:

```
[2023-12-13 08:50:48Z INFO HostContext] Well known config file 'Proxy': '/home/mo/azure-agent/.proxy'
[2023-12-13 08:50:48Z ERR  VstsAgentWebProxy] The proxy url is not a well formed absolute uri string: "http://proxy.domain.com:SOME_PORT".
[2023-12-13 08:50:48Z INFO VstsAgentWebProxy] No proxy setting found.
```

Nothing shows up for this error on the internet.

I'm currently trying to understand the [code where the error comes from](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent/VstsAgentWebProxy.cs), see line 156 *private void LoadProxySetting()*. It seems something is wrong with the file URI.

(All paths are relative to agent's root directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the .proxy file was missing. The following fixed the error:

```bash
echo http://proxy.domain.com:SOME_PORT > .proxy
```

Make sure `.proxy` content is without any quotes.

For internet access to work again, also check files like `.env` and `runsvc.sh` (or wherever you export your environment). I had a line `export http_proxy="http://proxy.domain.com:SOME_PORT"` where I also had to remove the quotes.

Note:
It's still unclear, why this issue only appeared after the agents were running fine for months. The root cause is still unclear, maybe some update.

Comment: I don't see any recent updates that may cause this issue. The reason is not certain, `.proxy` file may have been accidentally deleted or corrupted by a user or a program. It's suggested that you could update the agent to the latest version and monitor it to check if the `.proxy` file will miss again.

Comment: Hi @Mo_, in order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept your answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks for sharing with us!